# Is migration required after adding an extra storage map to a pallet

Tags: runtime, runtime-upgrade, storagemap

From my understanding how the runtime store its state adding an extra storage variable like

```rust
  pub Verified (get fn is_verified): map hasher(blake2_128_concat) us64 => ();
```

to a pallet that already has storage state like

```rust
  pub Member (get fn membership_info): map hasher(blake2_128_concat) u64 => Member;
```

With `Member` being say a `struct` containing various fields.

This **Should Not** require a runtime upgrade. But if I decide to add a boolean flag to the `Member` data structure then a runtime upgrade is required.
Am I correct in all of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

Adding new storage types do not require any migrations. However, they are also not present in the storage. So, if you require that a storage item is set to a certain value, you need a migration to initialize the value.

If you are changing the `Member` struct by adding or removing a value, you are changing its encoded format and require a migration to fix up all storage items.